# Scipy UnivariateSpline crashes

Tags: python, scipy

I have a strange crash with scipy `UnivariateSpline`.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline, UnivariateSpline
df = pd.read_csv('pbuniv.csv',sep=';')
float_t0 = df['time'].min()
func_nitp = UnivariateSpline(df['time']-float_t0, df['n2_2'], k=1, s=0.1)
```

Here is dataframe:

```
Unnamed: 0 time n2_2  
0  1917  958.5  65.000000  
1  1918  959.0  58.000000  
2  1919  959.5  55.000000  
3  1922  961.0  44.000000  
4  1923  961.5  42.000000  
5  1925  962.5  38.000000  
6  1926  963.0  35.000000  
7  1927  963.5  34.000000  
8  1929  964.5  31.000000  
9  1930  965.0  29.000000  
10 1931  965.5  28.000000  
11 1934  967.0  24.000000  
12 1935  967.5  23.000000  
13 1936  968.0  22.500000  
14 1939  969.5  20.000000  
15 1940  970.0  19.000000  
16 1941  970.5  18.500000  
17 1944  972.0  16.000000  
18 1946  973.0  15.000000  
19 1947  973.5  14.000000  
20 1950  975.0  13.000000  
21 1951  975.5  12.666667  
22 1955  977.5  11.000000  
23 1956  978.0  10.500000
```

I am currently using scipy 1.5.2 and python 3.7.4 with Spyder 3.3.6.

With this data, I get a kernel crash.
If I remove the first or last line of the input, it runs perfectly.

Any clue what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segfault problem seems to come from the smoothing factor *s* you're using when optimizing your spline. In your case, when *s* is too small, the iterative process can lead to a segfault. Either use s=0 (letting the spline interpolate between every points), or choose s>0.2 in your case (s=10 works fine too :) )

```
   import pandas as pd
   from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline, UnivariateSpline
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   %matplotlib inline
   df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep=';')
   float_t0 = df['time'].min()
   func_nitp = UnivariateSpline(df['time']-float_t0, df['n2_2'], k=1, s=0.2)

   xs = np.linspace(-1, 25, 100)
   plt.plot(xs, func_nitp(xs), 'g', lw=3)
   plt.scatter(df['time']-float_t0, df['n2_2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but this looks similar known issue https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3691

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like it's a smoothing problem. s=0.2 works fine.

Comment: Would be nice to check if splrep with the same s value works